# ZDesigner Thermal Label Printer - Corrupted Labels

Tags: pdf, printing, printer, adobe-acrobat

[Corrupted Label Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bm3z7.jpg)

Does anyone know what could cause this? We have been using this printer for the past month or 2 with no issues and now all of a sudden, it has started to produce labels like this.

We print labels off with customer details on [with a barcode for tracking] for couriers like DHL, DPD etc.

The labels are always printed off from a PDF using Adobe Acrobat Reader DC. Because of the corruption, we tried Chrome & Microsoft Edge to print them and they produce the same result.

The printer was producing labels as normal this morning up until about 10am, then after about an hour, we printed some more, but they started coming out like the attached.

Printer is hooked up via Serial / USB cable on a Windows 10 Home, 64 bit, Ver 10.0.19041.

Printer model is: Zebra GK420D

Comment: Rebooted the printer and/or the computer it is attached to?

Comment: @Mokubai yes, this doesn't work, tried resetting printer to defaults, recalibrating etc

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a possibility to print Zebra native files? (it is a good 30 years ago or so when I worked with a Zebra dealer who did develop their own label designer, so my knowledge is ancient).

As other software does not create proper labels either, it could be a Zebra issue.

On Acrobat Reader's side, you might try printing as Image (from Print dialog, go to the Advanced setup page, where you can check `Print as Image`)

Comment: Hi Max, this option is greyed out for me, I can't tick the box